# Should I throw PDOException from my PDO class extension?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I'm extending PDO and I want to throw exceptions from it. Should I make my own exception class that is not inherited from PDOException, throw PDOException or throw a class inherited from PDOException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your exception does not contain any extra data or custom properties, just throw the original `PDOException`, as you have no reason to extend it.